# Dependency Injection with Generic Interface and Simple Injector

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I am trying to implement dependency injection with Simple Injector and ASP.NET Core. I have a class library for services and another class library for data access with repositories. My problem is, I have implemented dependency injection in my startup class (web api) to reference my services. Now I need to do the same in the services to injection dependency for repositories. But I don't have a startup class in my class library (services class library), so how can I do it?

```
public interface IBaseService<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    { }
```

Account service

```
    public interface IAccountService : IBaseService<User>
{ }


 private readonly IAccountRepository _repository;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public AccountService(IAccountRepository repository, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork) : base (repository, unitOfWork)
    {
        _repository = repository;
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }
```

Repository (in a different class library):

```
   public interface IBaseRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question boils down to the following simple question:

> Where should we compose object graphs?

The answer to this question is:

> As close as possible to the application's entry point.

This entry point is commonly referred to as the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/).

In other words, *all* your dependencies should be wired up in the Composition Root, independently of in which layer they live. Your Composition Root is a layer on its own, and it knows about every other part of the system (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501604/ioc-di-why-do-i-have-to-reference-all-layers-assemblies-in-entry-application)).

So considering the displayed code, your Composition Root might look something as follows:

```
container.Register<IAccountService, AccountService>();
container.Register<IAccountRepository, AccountRepository>();
container.Register<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

Long story short, libraries don't have a Composition Root and you don't wire dependencies in the library itself. You compose all object graphs solely in the startup project.